# Where can I find the source code of Quickly?

Tags: quickly, source-code

I am looking for the source code of Quickly so that I can better understand it and use that knowledge to build my application that interacts with the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps, you can try taking a look at the source code of quickly. To do that, run the following command in a terminal:

```
apt-get source quickly
```

For the command to work, you need to have enabled *Source code* in the `software-properties-gtk`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Search for projects on Launchpad with the key word "quickly", there are few of them, copy the link to the ppa of that project and simpy do:

```
bzr branch ppa:/link/to/ppa
```